# Jensen's inequality - weaker condition? David Williams

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In *David William's, Probability with Martingales*, he wrote:

> Suppose that $c:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function on an open subinterval $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $X$ is a random variable such that
>   $$ E(|X|)<\infty, \quad P(X \in G) =1, \quad E(|c(X)|)<\infty. $$ 
>   Then 
>   $$E(c(X)) \ge c(E(X)). $$

The proof is done by obtaining inequality

> $$ c(X) \ge m(X- \mu) + c(\mu) $$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega$, where $\mu:=E(X)$.

and applying integration to both sides.

---

So as long as $\int c(X) \, dP$ exists, which need not be finite, the inequality still holds?

Comment: If $c(X)$ is almost surely nonnegative and $E(c(X))$ is infinite, the inequality oes not seem to have a very strong content, right?

Comment: In fact the situation is much better. The inequality tells that $\mathbb{E}[c(X)_{-}]<\infty$ as long as $X$ is integrable, so the expectation of $c(X)$ always exists in $(-\infty,\infty]$ and satisfies the Jensen’s inequality.

Comment: Thanks sangchul, so to confirm: the condition $E(|c(X)|)<\infty$ was unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, that condition is not necessary. Of course, except the fact that existence of $E[c(X)]$ can be absorbed into part of the conclusion, Did’s comment is right in that the inequality will carry non-trivial information only when $c(X)$ is also integrable.